# Simple WPF ItemsSource Control

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemssource

This feels like a stupid question, but is there a simple control for WPF that just displays a collection of items? I am currently using a ListBox to display a collection of usercontrols, but the selection element is not needed and the highlighting is actually a distraction. I could disable the highlighting, but this seems like extra work if a simpler control exists. I don't need to track the selected item.

Basically, I want a stackpanel that I can just define an itemssource of viewmodels for. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an ItemsControl - it's pretty much exactly what you are looking for

Comment: I knew this was a stupid question, I don't know how I missed that one. This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!